# Fixing Multi-site files path

Tags: 7, multi-sites

I have two separate **fully developed** Drupal 7 sites, which I now want to make as Multi-site.

[image]

I did it like in the above pic, and it worked, except all the images on both sites are broken.

Upon inspecting element, the paths are still trying to read from `/sites/default/files` folder instead of `/sites/site1.com/files` and `/sites/site2.com/files` respectively.

How can I fix the paths so it reads from `/sites/site1.com/files` and `/sites/site2.com/files`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be aware of this. Change file path for individual sites at `Configuration/Media/File system`. By default it is set to `sites/default/files`. So your both sites are addressing same path.

[image]

So just change the path there accordingly for both sites.

Comment: Looks like @NoSssweat is too much involved with D8, which results in forgetting how D7 works, no?